# Join / subquery confusion in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I've re-written my query until I can't take it any more, so I was wondering if there is a better solution?

I have 5 tables;

- a "contact" table which holds all the contact notes added by agents to People (enquiries the agents are contacting).
- a "people" table which holds the enquiries
- a "users" table which holds the agents
- a "division" table which holds which 'department' the agent looks after
- a "peopleOwners" table which holds records of who 'owns' the enquiries

The peopleOwners is a list of the ID's of the people and users (so more than one person can own a contact).

The contact table holds who and when a person was contacted (as well as the contact note obviously).

I'm trying to get a list of agents with the days since they last contacted each of their owned contacts (also those they haven't contacted yet).

My issue is that I need to get:

- a result row for each agent within a division
- a row for each enquiry (or 'People' row) that they are the owner of
- the date of the last contact they added for that enquiry.

I am using a subquery but it's taking around 40 seconds so isn't really viable - I've checked and indexes look ok, the query is using 2 file scans which obviously isn't good!

```
SELECT po.FK_DivisionID, division_Name, po.FK_UserID_Owner, u.name, 
       p.PK_PeopleID, CONCAT_WS(' ', ppl_Title, ppl_FirstName,
       ppl_LastName) AS fullName, cc.maxID, cc.lastContact

  FROM People AS p, Users AS u, Divisions AS d, PeopleOwners AS po

  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT contact_inputbyID, FK_PeopleID, MAX(c.contact_created) AS maxID,
                   DATEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(c.contact_created)) AS lastContact
            FROM Contact AS c
            GROUP BY FK_PeopleID
            ) AS cc
            ON cc.contact_inputbyID = po.FK_UserID_Owner
            AND cc.FK_PeopleID=po.FK_PeopleID

 WHERE po.FK_PeopleID = p.PK_PeopleID
   AND po.peopleowner_removed IS NULL
   AND po.FK_DivisionID=d.PK_DivisionID
   AND po.FK_UserID_Owner=u.PK_UserID
```

If anyone can give me some pointers in how to optimise it, it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

SqlFiddle of what I mean:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff7e62/2
(the fiddle works but in the live system the query is slow due to temporary table / file scans I think - is there a more optimised version possible?)

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of knew it wouldn't make sense without some data but didn't realise sqlfiddle existed.  :-)   Try this please: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff7e62/2   It gives the right results but on large tables isn't very fast - I think due to table / file scans.

Comment: Execute your query preceded by `EXPLAIN` and then share the results

Comment: Tables need PRIMARY KEYS!!!

Comment: Sorry, the 'live' tables do have primary keys and indexes.